# How to page jump within a tab on the same page

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I am trying to insert a page jump which needs to open a new section/tab on the same page

like shown here

http://www.ebay.com/itm/Sony-CDX-GT540UI-CD-MP3-Car-Audio-Receiver-Front-USB-Input-iPod-controls-/390406795334?pt=Car_Audio_In_Dash_Receivers&vxp=mtr&hash=item5ae60ef046

you have shipping, payment, return policy etc. I am trying to put a link that says

Click Here To View Warranty Details right above the product pictures directly under where it says comes with a 1 year warranty. I am able to either have the tab opened when I click the link or have the page jump down to that section but not open the other tab.

Here is the code I am using

```
<a href="nogo" onclick="return show('tab3')">Click Here To View Warranty Details</a>
```

but this will not do the page jump to the return policy it only opens the Returns Policy Tab without making the jump. What am I missing how or what else am I supposed to do? I have replaced the  and jump the page but it doesn't happen. Thank you so much for all your help I really do appreciate it.

Below is a link to the code I am working with its a text file thanks again!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7cikzfk5u31vvec/Page%20Jump.txt

Comment: Have you tried href="#tab3" instead of href="nogo"?  Your show('tab3') would have to return true for that to actually work though.

Comment: How would I make it show true instead?
<a href="#tab3" onclick="return show('tab3')">Click Here To View Warranty Details</a>

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<a onclick="location.href='#policies'; return show('tab3');" href="nogo">Click Here To View Warranty Details</a>
```

Comment: You are still going to have a problem when it's live on ebay, b/c it's in an iframe, and all this will do is scroll to the bottom of that iframe. But if the ebay page isn't scrolled down far enough to see the bottom, this will not be useful.  It's the same code you are using for the 'returns' tab at the top.

Comment: Hit the check box to the left of this answer if you are satisfied with the answer. Good Luck!

Comment: So how do I avoid the Iframe problem?

Comment: I see that same thing happens is there any way to work around that?

Comment: Sorry, not unless Ebay offers some custom solution like Facebook provides. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366770/change-window-location-when-iframe-location-is-changed

Comment: is there any way to do the page jump without using an iframe code?

Answer (score 0):

First of all create an id with a name at the place where you want to link the page.

```
<span class="headline" id="History">History</span>
```

then use the below code at the place where you want to create the page down link.

```
<a href="#History">History</a>
```

Now when you click on "History" the page will jump to the the code where you have created the id.

Comment: Thank you that works and will do the page jump but it won't open the Returns Policy tab is there something else I can add to open that Returns Tab? Perhaps I am adding it in the wrong place?

Comment: Sorry but I can't help in that regard.